# How do I pass multiple arguments to a ruby method as an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, methods, arguments

I have a method in a rails helper file like this

```
def table_for(collection, *args)
 options = args.extract_options!
 ...
end
```

and I want to be able to call this method like this

```
args = [:name, :description, :start_date, :end_date]
table_for(@things, args)
```

so that I can dynamically pass in the arguments based on a form commit.  I can't rewrite the method, because I use it in too many places, how else can I do this?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Ruby handles multiple arguments well.

[Here is](https://web.archive.org/web/20170113103604/http://www.misuse.org/science/2008/01/30/passing-multiple-arguments-in-ruby-is-your-friend) a pretty good example.

```
def table_for(collection, *args)
  p collection: collection, args: args
end

table_for("one")
#=> {:collection=>"one", :args=>[]}

table_for("one", "two")
#=> {:collection=>"one", :args=>["two"]}

table_for "one", "two", "three"
#=> {:collection=>"one", :args=>["two", "three"]}

table_for("one", "two", "three")
#=> {:collection=>"one", :args=>["two", "three"]}

table_for("one", ["two", "three"])
#=> {:collection=>"one", :args=>[["two", "three"]]}
```

(Output cut and pasted from irb)

Comment: There is a *very* similar example in [Programming Ruby, Thomas & Hunt, 2001](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html) with a bit more explanation.  See chapter "More About Methods", section "Variable-Length Argument Lists".

Answer (score 69):

Just call it this way:

```
table_for(@things, *args)
```

The `splat` (`*`) operator will do the job, without having to modify the method.

Comment: I was trying to compose parameters for a fixed method from an array and your answer helped thanks e.g.;
`method(*['a', '', nil].compact_blank)`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hello
  $i=0
  def read(*test)
    $tmp=test.length
    $tmp=$tmp-1
    while($i<=$tmp)
      puts "welcome #{test[$i]}"
      $i=$i+1
    end
  end
end

p Hello.new.read('johny','vasu','shukkoor')
# => welcome johny
# => welcome vasu
# => welcome shukkoor
```

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Comment: first of all, create a pointer test,which is like an array,then, find the array length. then we have to iterate the loop till the counter reaches the length.then in loop it will print the welcome message with all the arguements in method

Comment: `i` is defined here as global variable. it will be set to zero only once, when class is loaded. so second run of `read` function will never work.