# Passing multiple arguments to variable argument ruby method using array

Tags: arrays, ruby, axlsx

I'm working with a ruby gem right now that takes in a variable number of arguments (to be specific, it's the axlsx gem).

I'm using the `column_width`s function, defined as:

```
def column_widths(*widths)
  widths.each_with_index do |value, index|
    next if value == nil
    Axlsx::validate_unsigned_numeric(value) unless value == nil
    find_or_create_column_info(index).width = value
  end
end
```

I have a dynamic number of widths that need to be set (because the number of columns varies), so I tried creating an array of widths and passing that in, but it treats the array as a single argument.

How can I pass in the array as a list of arguments?

Edit:

The actual error is:

> Invalid Data [30, 13, 20, 13, 20, 13, 20, 13, 10, 10, 10, 13, 20, 10]
>   for Invalid column width. must be [Fixnum, Integer, Float]

Comment: I think you're doing ok, what is the actual error? Btw, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/831280/1505348) question looks identical.

Comment: edited to reflect the actual error, and I looked at that, but it didn't answer my question or solve my problem

Comment: nevermind @Lucio, you're right - I saw that but somehow I skipped over the answers other than the top one. my bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the splat both at method definition and method invocation. This should work:

```
column_widths(*array_of_widths)
```

Comment: that worked - thanks